# GWT UIBinder IntegerBox is not stylish

Tags: gwt, uibinder

In our project we decided to try to design our UIs with UIBinder instead of doing everything in Java mixing GWT widgets and logic. We found out how much prettier they look panels, buttons and such from scratch, which saves a lot of time especially for presenting a demo. However, when we use number box widgets, like IntegerBox or DoubleBox, they don't appear as pretty as TextBoxes, they are like plain HTML boxes, thus quite ugly in contrast with the rest of the widgets. We did some Google search but nothing came up about this topic.

Is there any trick to accomplish this, to use GWT native number boxes with UIBinder and to appear in the pretty style? Or maybe we should just use TextBoxes for everything and write our own wrappers for setText-getText and parse the values.
This is really important as we have to make client-side calculations with input numbers before sending data back to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIBinder is not in any way responsible for things looking "pretty", it only generates Java code, the same kind of code that you were coding by hand previously. If things look "prettier", it's likely because you `<inherits>`-ed a theme in your gwt.xml.

Contrary to TextBox though, IntegerBox and DoubleBox don't have an associated hard-coded style name. If you want to have them style the same as every TextBox, you can then simply `addStyleName("gwt-TextBox")` to them (the hard-coded style name of the TextBox widget), or in your ui.xml: `<g:IntegerBox addStyleNames="gwt-TextBox" …` (note the plural here; this is documented in UIObject's javadoc).

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I see what happened:
Firstly, it's the first time we try UIBinder, so we didn't know how it would look like. Secondly, this UIBinder test was done in a new GWT project, GWT2.3. We thought that the new style for TextBoxes was for using UIBinder, but after your suggestion I had a look to gwt.xml and it's inheriting a new CSS style called "clean", apparently new in GWT2.3.